# Not all Bootstrap class are applying in React app

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm new to React. So currently I'm just blindly following some React lessons and trying to figure out how things are working.

I have stumbled upon issues when some styles shown in the lesson are not applying in my case:

```
export function SomeRenderer(props: MyProps) {
 // some logic
<p className="card-text font-italic">Rating: {rating}/10</p>
 // and
<div className="card-footer text-muted text-right">
```

So `font-italic` is not working (not applying, even though the class name is present in the DOM) and `text-right` as well is doing nothing.
However `card`, `card-footer`, `text-muted` etc. are working fine.

While I was searching on similar issues I was able to found the only suggestion which is adding `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";` to my entry point. But it is already there.

Another weird thing I notices that my fonts are looking crap comparing to the lesson and the documentation itself (Sorry, but I'm not really able to provide better explanation)

dependencies in package.json (created via create-react-app):

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.11",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.4",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think because bootstrap 5.0.0 is "fst-italic" not font-italic and "text-right" is "text-end"

**you use a bootstrap 4 class not v5**

see the docs for v5 [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/#text-alignment)